# TaskFactory.CompleteWhenBoth

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to construct something which would work a bit like `Zip` for two tasks, but I'm a bit worried about race conditions in this code.

```
public static Task<R> ContinueWhenBoth<T1, T2, R>(this TaskFactory<R> factory, Task<T1> t1, 
                                                 Task<T2> t2, Func<T1, T2, R> f)
{
    var result = new TaskCompletionSource<R>();

    t1.ContinueWith(t => { if(t2.IsCompleted) result.TrySetResult(f(t1.Result, t2.Result)); });
    t2.ContinueWith(t => { if(t1.IsCompleted) result.TrySetResult(f(t1.Result, t2.Result)); });

    return result.Task;
}
```

Is this a good way to go?

```
public static Task<R> ContinueWhenBoth<T1, T2, R>(this TaskFactory<R> factory, Task<T1> t1, 
                                                 Task<T2> t2, Func<T1, T2, R> f)
{
    var result = new TaskCompletionSource<R>();

    int tasksLeft = 2;
    t1.ContinueWith(t => 
                    {
                    if(Interlocked.Decrement(ref tasksLeft) == 0 && t2.IsCompleted) 
                        result.TrySetResult(f(t1.Result, t2.Result)); 
                    });
    t2.ContinueWith(t => 
                    {
                    if(Interlocked.Decrement(ref tasksLeft) == 0 && t1.IsCompleted) 
                        result.TrySetResult(f(t1.Result, t2.Result)); 
                    });

    return result.Task;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to write this code yourself, there is already a method that does something very similar: [`Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.continuewhenall.aspx).

`ContinueWhenAll()` doesn't directly support working with `Task`s that return different types, but you can create a helper method that does:

```
public static Task<R> ContinueWhenBoth<T1, T2, R>(
    this TaskFactory<R> factory, Task<T1> t1, Task<T2> t2, Func<T1, T2, R> f)
{
    return factory.ContinueWhenAll(new Task[] { t1, t2 }, _ => f(t1.Result, t2.Result));
}
```

If you didn't want to use closure for performance reasons, you could use the array of `Task`s and casting:

```
return factory.ContinueWhenAll(
    new Task[] { t1, t2 }, tasks => f(((Task<T1>)tasks[0]).Result, ((Task<T2>)t2).Result));
```

---

```
t1.ContinueWith(t => { if(t2.IsCompleted) result.TrySetResult(f(t1.Result, t2.Result)); });
t2.ContinueWith(t => { if(t1.IsCompleted) result.TrySetResult(f(t1.Result, t2.Result)); });
```

This code has a race condition: if `t1` and `t2` complete at the same time, then `f` might be executed twice. I don't think that's a good idea, since `f` might take a long time, or, worse, it might have side-effects.

```
if(Interlocked.Decrement(ref tasksLeft) == 0 && t2.IsCompleted)
```

The `Decrement()` here avoids the race condition from the previous code. But it also means that the check of `t2.IsCompleted` will always succeed, so you should remove it.

---

But your code also has a significant issue: if `t1` or `t2` fail with an exception, your resulting `Task` will never complete. (And on .Net 4.0, it will also crash the process some time in the future, because there is an uncaught exception in a `Task`.)

Comment: Can it combine input tasks of different types?

Comment: @Benjol See edit.

Comment: OK, I see. I'll try that. One thing I don't understand is you say that `t2.IsCompleted` will always succeed: surely only if t2 completes first?

Comment: @Benjol I mean, if the first condition succeeds, the second one will too, so there is no reason to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you are using .NET 4.5? It contains the method that does exactly what you need: [Task.WhenAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374.aspx).

Comment: No quite (I think), because my tasks have different types